# Custom view is invalidated without onDraw called after bitmap manipulation

Tags: android, bitmap, android-canvas, android-view, ondraw

I have a custom View and it is redrawn when the drawn bitmap is manipulated from another thread even though `onDraw` is never called. If I stop calling  `resetBitmap` auto redraw issue won't happen.

```
mainHandler.post(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
         resetBitmap();
         doBitmapManipulation(); 
    }
});


private void resetBitmap() {
    sessionCanvas.drawBitmap(sourceBitmap, 0, 0, null);
}
```

Here is my onDraw

```
@Override
public void onDraw(Canvas canvas){
    canvas.drawBitmap(sessionBitmap, 0, 0, paint);
}
```

SessionCanvas

```
sessionCanvas = new Canvas(sessionBitmap);
```

Comment: Edited the question. sessionCanvas holds the actual bitmap that will be drawn in the onDraw

Comment: Are you calling `invalidate()` externally after updating the bitmap ?

Comment: I do not call invalidate() and I put a Log to see if onDraw ever called, it is never called but view is invalidated.